# LibreOffice XForm : how to read form data with javascript macro

Tags: javascript, macros, libreoffice, xforms

I have an XForm document in LibreOffice Writer 5. The form contains various text boxes and date fields. What I want is to create a Javascript macro that will be assigned to one text box and perform some actions whenever the user changes the input of this field. So far I have written the following

```
var oDoc = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel, XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getInvocationContext());
if (!oDoc) {
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument();
}
var xFieldsSupplier = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XFormsSupplier, oDoc);
var xForm = xFieldsSupplier.getXForms();
```

but *xForm* is null. Does anyone know how I can get the XForm fields? Is there something wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.  It seems to be an issue with Javascript, because I tested similar code using other languages and it worked.  In Python this printed the form name:

```
xforms = oDoc.getXForms()
formName = xforms.getElementNames()[0]
xTextRange = xText.getEnd()
xTextRange.setString(formName)
xform = xforms.getByName(formName)
```

The same thing worked in Java:

```
XFormsSupplier xFormsSupplier = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XFormsSupplier.class, xComponent);
XNameContainer xforms = xFormsSupplier.getXForms();
String formName = xforms.getElementNames()[0];
xTextRange = xText.getEnd();
xTextRange.setString(formName);
Object aForm = xforms.getByName(formName);
```

[This introduction](https://www.openoffice.org/framework/scripting/release-0.2/javascript-devguide.html) indicates that Javascript support for UNO is still in its infancy.

Note that [XFormsSupplier](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/xforms/XFormsSupplier.html) is not published, which presumably means the interface is subject to change or instability.